# Have nested cell stay on right while you can type on the left of the cell normally

Tags: html, css, html-table, nested, cell

I am making a table in HTML and I am trying to have it so the box labeled homework stays on the right of the cell and the user can type on the left without the box moving and messing it up. Is there a way I can make the box stay in the top right corner and have the user be able to type with a constraint on the right side but still be able to expand the box downwards for overflow?

You can find a snippet of my code attached.
It should include everything you will need, but if you need more just let me know. Thanks.

```css
.plannerBox {
    outline: 2px solid black;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.homeworkCategory {
    color: white;
    background-color: gray;
    outline: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>Planner - My Digital Planner</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
        <tr>
            <td class="plannerBox" id="iR2C2" contenteditable="true" placeholder="Work goes here."><table class="homeworkCategory"><td contenteditable="false">Homework</td></table>text would go here, and here, and here aswell</td>
      
      </table>
```

You can't see it aswell in this snippet, so below you can see what it looks like on the web.
[image]

Below you can find a example of what I am trying to accomplish. [image]

Thank you.

Comment: Almost all of it repeats for the HTML for the 58 cells. You only need to look at one.

Comment: ok, I did it quickly and did not realize how much unnecessary code was there. I removed almost all of the code.

Comment: Also this is not strictly tabular data imo. a CSS-Grid would be a better solution IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

I think it simply boils down to using `float:right` on the `homeworkCategory` class... and **removing** the `white-space:nowrap` from the `plannerBox` class.

There is also no need to have a full `<table>` for that "homework", so have swapped it for a simple `<span>` instead

Here is a simple example of the float...

```css
span {
  float:right;
  color:Red;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>hello world</span>
      hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world 
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I appreciate this answer very much, but while this was almost perfect; I still have one issue. I can't have text under the span.

Comment: *I can't have text under the span*... but isn't text under the span **exactly** what your hand drawn diagram shows as the required result??

Comment: I am sorry for not being clear, I mean it won’t let me put text under it, it just makes a new line on the left side of the span.

Comment: It keeps pushing the span further to the right with a large gap in between the text and the span.

Comment: @Robot123 - remove the `white-space: nowrap;` command